# Change occupancy grid axis

Tags: navigation, mapping, occupancy-grid

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I have lots of information been published to the XZ axis. Now, I'm publishing a 2D occupancy grid, but it is in the XY axis.
It is possible to change it to XZ as well?
Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/361505/change-occupancy-grid-axis/) by [mirella melo](https://answers.ros.org/users/55539/mirella-melo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 194 on 2020-09-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
grid_map.info.origin.orientation.x = 0.7071068;
grid_map.info.origin.orientation.y = 0.0;
grid_map.info.origin.orientation.z = 0.0;
grid_map.info.origin.orientation.w = 0.7071068;
```

---

Originally posted by [mirella melo](https://answers.ros.org/users/55539/mirella-melo/) with karma: 194 on 2020-09-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0